# System Settings won't open on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 17.10

I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.10, via 17.04. After the upgrade, I cannot access the system settings window. When I try to open it through the terminal, this is the error produced.

```
anomitra@C3PO:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ [INFO 14:56:15.591156] 
Application.vala:153: System Settings version: 2.0
[INFO 14:56:15.591186] Application.vala:155: Kernel version: 4.13.0-
16-generic
[WARNING 14:56:15.635521] PluginManager.vala:115: Unable to scan 
plugins folder: Error opening directory '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-
gnu/pantheon-online-accounts': No such file or directory
[FATAL 14:56:15.711890] PlugsManager.vala:58: get_plug () not found in 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/switchboard/system/pantheon-
useraccounts/guest-session-toggle
[ERROR 14:56:15.717373] [GLib-GIO] Settings schema 'org.pantheon.dpms' 
is not installed
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What command did you run?

Comment: I ran `gnome-control-settings`

Comment: Aren't you talking about ElementaryOS by any chance?

Comment: No, not at all. I'm on Ubuntu. I think 17.10 uses Pantheon in some way.

Comment: Someone opened a bug report for this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1721637. If this affects you, please click on "This bug affects me" on that page.

Comment: After running gnome-control-settings I get a "segmentation fault"

Comment: In my case, there was a dead old "gnome-control-settings" process running in the background. Killed it and voila!

Answer (score 6):

You can try to reinstall gnome-control-center from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, sadly.

Comment: I get :
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

(gnome-control-center:7059): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Doesn't work for me as well. Anyone solved this yet?

Comment: See Aram Paronikyan's comment above.  Search for an already-running process, e.g. `$ ps aux | grep gnome-control-center` and then kill the process.  After doing that, it may launch properly.